# Activate and Deactivate Marketing Assets Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, automation, dynamics-365

I need help with a small problem in Dynamics 365 Marketing App.

Is there a way to access the "Stop" and "Go live" Button via code or the actions that happen when it gets clicked.

We need to stop the marketing assets and than activate them again, so they can be used in a customer journey.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it in two ways: **Client-side** (JavaScript) or **Server-side** (C# plugin or Workflow)

Use ribbon workbench to hook the `Go-Live` action & call custom javascript function or custom Action [Ribbon button customization](https://community.dynamics.com/365/marketing/f/dynamics-365-for-marketing-forum/369317/custom-validation-script-in-go-live-button-is-not-working)

Otherwise register a post-update plugin to do what you want [Basic operations on Customer Journey using the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/developer/basic-operations-on-customer-journey)